# How do I create a spring boot listener for azure service bus FIFO queue?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azureservicebus, spring-jms, fifo

I am trying to write a listener for azure service bus queue, but the messages aren't being pulled. The sender is working, so I know it's not a networking issue. The messages are being sent with a sessionId for FIFO, which I believe is causing the issue. Perhaps it requires more code for the listener, or a custom listener factory. However, I have been unable to find a reference for creating a FIFO listener.

```
@JmsListener(destination="request", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(String message) {
    try {
        log.debug("Azure message received: {}", message);
        myService.process(message);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while processing message: {}", message, e);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  jms:
    servicebus:
      connection-string: Endpoint=sb://myapp.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=enable_access_from_resource_group;SharedAccessKey=<mykey>
      idle-timeout: 30000
azure:
  servicebus:
    queue-receive-mode: peeklock
    queue-name: myqueue
    connection-string: Endpoint=sb://myapp.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=enable_access_from_resource_group;SharedAccessKey=<myKey>
    allow-telemetry: false
```

messaging.tf

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "alpha" {
  name                = "myapp"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.k8s.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.k8s.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  tags = {
    app = var.cluster_name
  }
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "request" {
  name                         = "request"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.k8s.name
  namespace_name               = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.alpha.name
  enable_partitioning          = false
  requires_duplicate_detection = true
  requires_session             = true
}
```

Comment: have you refer this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus

Comment: any updates on this?